# Problem in connecting wired network

Tags: lts, wired

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04 gnome version

Wired network shows connecting icon but actually not getting connected

Comment: What does ping -c 4 google.com and ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 tell you ?

Comment: On executing ping -c 4 google.com and ping -c 4 8.8.8.8, it shows ping: unknown host google.com and connect: Network is unreachable, respectively @serg

Comment: Try doing `sudo service network-manager restart` to restart network-manager and re-establish the connection. Also, try removing all the files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and then reconnecting. You can do so by doing `sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* && sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Still its not working. Although, the ethernet cable is connected, it shows disconnected icon @Serg

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if the wired network is actually working correctly. Do you know if other people or machines are actually able to connect using a wired connection on the same network.

Second, I would check if the network adapter is functioning correctly. Is the same network adapter able to connect successfully on another network?

Thirdly, check if you are able to get an IP address via DHCP on the network. You can do this by running ifconfig from a terminal.

You may also need to confirm whether network policies are in place that may be limiting your ability to connect on the wired network.

Comment: 1,2,4 holds good. 3 ifconfig is not depicting any IP address. Only hardware is shown